# RecyclerView in a Fragment not loading

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

Tl:dr: I created my own bottom nav bar which redirects to 3 different fragments. 1 fragment (Trips) has a recyclerview in which I am displaying 3 info (ImageView, 2 TextViews). This recyclerview doesn't load (no error message), there is a blank screen on that fragment.
I suspect that the issue lies in the way I load the recycler from the Fragment Java class but had no success (went through multiple YT tutorials and the stackoverflow articles I could find)

Some of the steps that I tried (I am relatively new to Android so tried different scenarios)
- Clean project
- Check the @override (other stackoverflow article)
- in the fragment: splitted my code in 2: OncreateView where I inflate the layout and OnViewCreated where I load the adapter.
- the other fragment (with hardcoded text) works which indicates that the Fragmentmanager seems to work

Thanks for any advice

---

### Fragment

```
package com.example.projectapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ListAdapter;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;

    public class Trip extends Fragment {


        private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
        private RecyclerView recyclerView;
        private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;


        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_trips, container, false);

            RecyclerView recyclerView= (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
            adapter listAdapter= new adapter();
            recyclerView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager= new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            return v;
        }}




    ---------------------------------------------------------
    Adapter class
    ---------------------------------------------------------


    package com.example.projectapp;

    import android.provider.ContactsContract;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;

    public class adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<adapter.adapterview> {
        public class adapterview extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

            public LinearLayout linearLayout;
            public ImageView imageView;
            public TextView title;
            public TextView short_desc;


            public adapterview(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                linearLayout=itemView.findViewById(R.id.card);
                imageView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.pix);
                title=itemView.findViewById(R.id.titlecard);
                short_desc=itemView.findViewById(R.id.short_desc);

            }


        }

        public List<card> item_list= Arrays.asList(
                new card(R.drawable.ic_home,"this is a test","testing 2"),
                new card(R.drawable.ic_home,"this is a test1","testing 3"),
                new card(R.drawable.ic_home,"this is a test2","testing 4")
                );

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public adapterview onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card,parent,false);
            return new adapterview(v);
                }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull adapterview holder, int position) {
            card current= item_list.get(position);
            holder.title.setText(current.getTitle());
            holder.short_desc.setText(current.getDesc());
            holder.imageView.setImageResource(current.getimage());
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return item_list.size();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't call the recycler on onCreateView, do it in onViewCreated.

```
@Override
public View onViewCreated(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            RecyclerView recyclerView= (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
            adapter listAdapter= new adapter();
            recyclerView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager= new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this version (choosing the Void OnViewCreated though as nothing was return) but unfortunately still no luck (blank screen)

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `RecyclerView` adapter after you set its `LayoutManager`. So reorder the lines to be:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);   
adapter listAdapter= new adapter();
recyclerView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I edited my code but still no luck. As there aren't too many CL in the Fragment part I started to look at my adapter but still don't get what could go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Good news I fixed the issue (but unsure of the root cause though). I basically did 2 changes in case this helps others:
1. I passed to my adapter (in the fragment file) a list of object and the context. 
2. I removed 1 Textview from my layout (item from a recycler view) which could have prevented it from loading (?)

Now, next challenge trying to use a cardview as this linearlayout isn't great
thanks all